External callouts from Salesforce to third-party services that mandate IP restrictions
We make external callouts from Salesforce to a third-party - let's call them XYZ for this discussion.
We currently use MuleSoft for for this integration - there's a Salesforce experience API and an XYZ system API in MuleSoft. The third-party, XYZ, requires IP restrictions and we were able to whitelist the MuleSoft IPs in XYZ.
We're looking to move away from MuleSoft (for reasons I won't go into), but I'm wondering how we can achieve the IP whitelisting to XYZ without MuleSoft in the picture.
We use AWS a lot and we could deploy a proxy service to AWS (e.g. nginx or an AWS Lambda or something) where external requests egress via a NAT gateway with a static IP (which we could whitelisted in XYZ), but we don't have SF private connect, so external callouts from SF to AWS would be over the public Internet (which isn't ideal), plus we'd probably need to implement some kind of auth / access control on the proxy.
Just wondering what other options there might be for making external callouts from SF to third-party services that mandate IP restrictions...

we could deploy a proxy service where external requests egress via a NAT gateway with a static IP...we'd probably need to implement some kind of auth / access control on the proxy - sounds like you've answered your own question. AWS has lots of options for getting a static IP - Global Accelerator, ALB, Elastic IP. NAT, and more.  Pick a solution architecture and try it out.

It seems, you've answered your own question. I just want to highlight that even if external callouts from SF would be over the public Internet, still you can add the following measures to secure it.

Add SF Region Specific IP ranges to the external server.
Add two-way SSL authentication for your Callouts.

